# Checking a check box that can be checked

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

To share a profile, check box is used.
There are three type of check boxes

1. check box which is read-only
2. check box which is already checked
3. check box which is not checked

In the above scenario, how to verify using selenium web-driver (java)

1. verify read-only check box is read-only
2. verify checking a check box whether checked or not
3. how to automate checking a check box when there are multiple
   unchecked check box

Comment: I haven't started writing the code as i'm not sure how to write it

HTML for checked box:
<tr>
<td>
<div>name last(test)</div>
<div>test@test.com</div>
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="35" name="checkUser">
</td>
<td>
<span class="perm">
<span class="perm">
<span class="perm">
<span class="perm">
<span class="perm">
</td>
</tr>

HTML Code for Read Only check box:
<tr>
<td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" value="313" name="checkUser">
</td>
<td>
</tr>

Comment: @Nagarjun: Please edit your question and add the html from your above comment there.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
boolean b=driver.findElement(By.name("Check Box Locator")).isEnabled();
```

above code returns true if checked and false if not checked....

or try this code too...

```
String status=driver.findElement(By.name("Check Box Locator")).getAttribute("Checked");
```

this string prints the attribute value whether it is checked or unckecked

based on attribute value you can prepare your report

hope this helps you